# Rails hang in Thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I am trying to make a single-threaded part multi-threaded. The initial single thread code works fine, but after I put it into a thread, the server hangs without any log information in the console.

Initial version:

```
data_array.each do |data|
  service = SomeService.new(data)
  data['answers'] = service.answer_data
end
```

Multi-threaded version:

```
threads = []
threads << Thread.new {
  data_array.each do |data|
    service = SomeService.new(data)
    data['answers'] = service.answer_data
  end
}
threads.each(&:join)
```

I tried binding.pry and get some more information:

1. I have a `Class` called `AggregationReport < Report`
2. When `SomeService` tried to run `AggregationReport.new`, it's stuck there forever.

Please help me understand what is happening here, any thoughts/help would be much appreciated!

---

Ruby version: Ruby27x
Rails: 5.2

Comment: If you're using activerecord - each thread will need to get access to a database connection and can block if there aren't sufficient connections in the pool. Is the service/report using the database? If so, see https://makandracards.com/makandra/45360-using-activerecord-with-threads-might-use-more-database-connections-than-you-think

Comment: Also - can you add the versions of ruby, rails and any gems that the hanging-report code uses? It's possible your report (or some gem it's using)

Answer (score 3):

I'm making some assumptions about why you're threading this, but I'd expect typical threading code to follow the following basic structure:

```
threads = data_array.map do |data|
  Thread.new { SomeService.new(data).answer_data }
end

answers = threads.map(&:value)
```

For each piece of work you need done:

1. Create a thread that does the work and stores the result in a threadsafe way
2. Join each thread to ensure execution (this is handled by #value)
3. Collect the results

If your service needs a database connection (e.g. postgres, redis, etc) you'll need to manage this as well. For activerecord add `ActiveRecord::Base.with_connection{ }` inside the thread to allocate a db connection. There are similar approaches for Redis/etc. Then ensure you have sufficient connections for the # of threads you want to create (look at the `pool:` setting in `config/database.yml`).

```
Thread.new { ActiveRecord::Base.with_connection{ SomeService.new(data).answer_data } }
```

For this and other reasons, it isn't always a great idea to spawn N threads, so instead of this approach you may consider using a thread pool of X and ensure you have a db connection pool of at least X+1 connections. All of this can be complex. There are great gems that sit on top of ruby threading and make it easier to do this exact kind of thing. I'd strongly recommend checking out [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) (bundled with Rails).

Comment: You could simplify your code by using [Thread#value](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-value) rather than resorting to thread-locals, e.g. `answers = data_array.map { |data| Thread.new {SomeService.new(data).answer_data} }.map(&:value)`. Also, rather than using `parallel`, in a Rails environment you already have [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) available which allows you to use thread pools and promises.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Why I want to make it multi-threaded is that each section of the data takes a long time to process, and I just want it to run faster. Yes, this service needs a database connection. I updated my testing code and removed the loop just to see what will happen if there is only one thread, then I ran into the same issue, still stuck at `AggregationReport.new`. `Thread.new { ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool,with_connection {SomeService.new(data).answer_data } }`. I check `pool:` and the number is 5, I changed it to a bigger number but still the same result.

Comment: If you stop the process when it's hanging you should get a stack-trace of where it was when the execution stops. If so - can you paste that into the question? It's possible there some other resource (similar to the database issue but something else) that it's blocked on

Comment: Or use the debugger / breakpoints to see where it's hanging

Comment: The process just stuck there without any errors. And if I stopped the process by crtl + c, it just shows interrupt. No other error. I tried breakpoints and found that the thread hang at `Class.new`. Then I added `binding.pry` right before `Class.new` and when it reaches there, I type `Class.new` in the console without type `next` or `step`, the process will hang too. So I guess the problem is I can't new a `Class` inside a thread.

Comment: Can you explain more about what the code is doing? (why are we creating a class? Is it being stored in a global constant?) It could be that the code you're trying to run is not threadsafe, especially if you're storing something in a class variable. Can this class be initialized before going into the threads?

Comment: Hey there, the Service is simply getting the data from the db and the `Class` is one of the models. The issue is probably related to development environment, after I run it in beta/prod environment the code works fine. I also saw some similar posts in StackOverflow and seems like none of them have found any solutions.

Comment: Oh, i thought you were creating a new class (with `Class.new`) rather than just an instance of a random class (e.g. `SomeClass.new`). You may try eager-loading the class definitions in dev to see if that avoids the problem.